# Happy sysadmin day 2013

Tags: discussion

Happy [sysadmin day](http://sysadminday.com/) to all.

> Friday, July 26, 2013, is the 14th annual System Administrator
>   Appreciation Day. On this special international day, give your System
>   Administrator something that shows that you truly appreciate their
>   hard work and dedication. (All day Friday, 24 hours, your own local
>   time-zone).

[Devotion to Duty](http://xkcd.com/705/)

[Sandwich](http://xkcd.com/149/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you!

bitcoin:153RzsnYzzRvreJ5WEK6oepAGJSWAX8GXb
litecoin:LSCYpu92yQBTUJ2uzoV4agdyD1S4VFrBMs

Answer (score 8):

Thank you. You may now shower me in cash and bitcoins 1F8BvgxErmevLhSbWJk3QatsVVTraLRnY8 .